# sending signed messages ethers

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js

Can you send a signed nested message within another signed message (with the signatories being different) in ethers?

The idea is to 'co sign' a message, and decode it on the smart contract (essentially moving some validation logic off chain to save gas).